# Run artisan in Laravel code without creating migration records in the table migrations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have this code in my function to run all migrations files in a folder to create new tables in a new database on the fly. However, every time I run it, it creates a new record in the table `migration` which is normal. But the next time I run the function again, the migration files are excluded because they have been run before.

How do I force it not to write anything to the table "migrations"? because I don't want this to be a part of the deployment. Those tables are used for creating new tenant client.

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'database/templates', '--force' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your goal better, it sounds like you wish to create additional tables when an event happens.

For this you'll just need to use the Schema builder to do it and avoid using migrations altogether. Consider the following example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

Schema::create('new_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    // additional columns
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

You can wrap this in a new class method to trigger when you want to create an additional table without effecting migrations.

If you wish to drop a table later you can run:

```
Schema::dropIfExists('new_table_name');
```

Comment: Can seeders create new tables?

Comment: @ln9187 I updated my answer, I think I get what you're trying to do now. Generate a new table for an additional entity without using migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can use the option `--pretend` to dump all the queries without writing the migration batch

```
Options:
      ...
      --pretend              Dump the SQL queries that would be run.
      ...
```